# Not able to print the desired output in python

Tags: python

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age): #contructor method
        self.name = name
        self.age = age 
        print '(0) has been born'.format(self.name) 
p1 = Person("sam", 23)
p2 = Person("sunny", 22)

Im getting output:-
(0) has been born
(0) has been born
Expected output:-
sam has been born
sunny has been born
```

I am trying here to learn about the special methods starting with the **init** method. But I am not getting the desired output. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use *curly brackets* `{}`:

```
print '{0} has been born'.format(self.name)
```

**Note:** You can see [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) from Python Docs for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me;

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age): #contructor method
        self.name = name
        self.age = age 
        print self.name+' has been born'
p1 = Person("sam", 23)
p2 = Person("sunny", 22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `{}` Check this [**`LIVE IDEONE`**](http://ideone.com/U7Y84p)

### Python

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age): #contructor method
        self.name = name
        self.age = age 
        print '{0} has been born'.format(self.name) 
p1 = Person("sam", 23)
p2 = Person("sunny", 22)
```

#### stdout

```
sam has been born
sunny has been born
```